# How can i use whereHas to get data from related mophic table in eloquent

Tags: laravel

i am using eloquent, any help!

```
return House::whereHas('extendable', function($extendUnits) use($projectdeciphered){
    $extendUnits->where('project_id', $projectdeciphered);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whereHasMorph as documented here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-morph-to-relationships

```
House::whereHasMorph('extendable', [Extend::class, Unit::class], function($extendUnits) use($projectDeciphered){
    $extendUnits->where('project_id', $projectDeciphered);
});
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Because i wanted one related mode House::whereHasMorph('extendable',  Unit::class, function($units) use($projectDeciphered){
    $units->where('project_id', $projectDeciphered);
});

Comment: @DeogratiasAlison , you wanted one related mode ? sorry, I don't get it. Can you explain more?